# Making proxy website for my project

Tags: php, web, proxy, youtube

I'm a student of computer science and having trouble in making my project.
What i have to do is to make a website which will open youtube and will play it by changing my ip. and seriously i am trying but dont know how to do this.Please show me any way.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Here is some web-based proxy script written in PHP:

> Glype Proxy Script - [Homepage](https://www.glype.com/)
>
> PHProxy - [Homepage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/files/latest/download?source=navbar)
>
> CGI Proxy - [Homepage](http://www.jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/)